# Limiting regex length

Tags: python, regex

I'm having an issue in python creating a regex to get each occurance that matches a regex.
I have this code that I made that I need help with.

```
strToSearch= "1A851B 1C331 1A3X1 1N111 1A3 and a whole lot of random other words."
print(re.findall('\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{3}', strToSearch.upper())) #1C331, 1N111
print(re.findall('\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[X]\d{1}', strToSearch.upper())) #1A3X1
print(re.findall('\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{3}[A-Z]{1}', strToSearch.upper())) #1A851B
print(re.findall('\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}', strToSearch.upper())) #1A3

>['1A851', '1C331', '1N111']
>['1A3X1']
>['1A851B']
>['1A8', '1C3', '1A3', '1N1', '1A3']
```

As you can see it returns "1A851" in the first one, which I don't want it to. How do I keep it from showing in the first regex? Some things for you to know is it may appear in the string like " words words 1A851B?" so I need to keep the punctuation from being grabbed.

Also how can I combine these into one regex. Essentially my end goal is to run an if statement in python similar to the pseudo code below.

```
lstResults = []
strToSearch= " Alot of 1N1X1 people like to eat 3C191 cheese and I'm a 1A831B aka 1A8."
lstResults = re.findall('<REGEX HERE>', strToSearch)
for r in lstResults:
    print(r)
```

And the desired output would be

```
1N1X1
3C191 
1A831B
1A8
```

Comment: do you want to explicitly ignore just `1A851` ?

Comment: I want to get the whole 'word' or string. I want to get 1A851B not 1A851.
I'm really bad at writing questions on here.

Comment: @darthvader1996
It seems that I needed to add \b to the end to filter the ones without the last letter on according to this [link](http://www.pyregex.com/?id=eyJyZWdleCI6IlxcZHsxfVtBLVpdezF9XFxkezN9XFxiIiwiZmxhZ3MiOjAsIm1hdGNoX3R5cGUiOiJmaW5kYWxsIiwidGVzdF9zdHJpbmciOiIxQTg1MUJcbjFBMzMxXG4xTjEzMT8ifQ%3D%3D)

Comment: Do these always begin with a digit?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes they will. There is a possibility in the future there will be one letter preceding but that is not likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With single *regex* pattern:

```
strToSearch= " Alot of 1N1X1 people like to eat 3C191 cheese and I'm a 1A831B aka 1A8."
lstResults = [i[0] for i in re.findall(r'(\d[A-Z]\d{1,3}(X\d|[A-Z])?)', strToSearch)]

print(lstResults)
```

The output:

```
['1N1X1', '3C191', '1A831B', '1A8']
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I figured there had to be something encapsulated in a parentheses.

However I still have one thing to throw at you. I also need to make sure that those are the only formats that can be returned. 

If I add "1A4D 5D33" to the string it will print them but I don't want them since it doesn't match the previous. I changed the expression you submitted to 
    "\d[A-Z](\d|\d{3})(X\d|[A-Z])?"

but it now returns 

    "['1N1X1', '3C1', '1A8', '1A8', '1A4D', '5D3']"

Comment: what does mean *since it doesn't match the **previous***?

Comment: It has to be in the format as these: `['1N1X1', '3C191', '1A831B', '1A8']`
So that means that these are incorrect and won't be added: `['1A4D', '5D33']`

Comment: @MatthewEnderle, it's hard to understand your logic. The pattern is common, why some items which fit the pattern should be skipped?

Comment: The values returned by this are being checked to see if they exist in a database. Let me break the codes out. First number is the group, first letter is an identifier, second number is a subIdentifier, X is a placeholder for where a number normally will be which is the skill level, and the last number is yet another identifier, and the last letter is optional which gives an additional detail.

So 1N1X1 could mean 1N151, just as 1A8 is a shortcode for 1A8X1. However 1A83 is not valid because it does not have the last required identifier.

Comment: I decided that I can use the regex you provided and just filter it out with python, and it did work that way. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yo may use word boundaries:

```
\b\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{3}\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mbzmv6/1)

For the combination, it is unclear the criterium according to which you consider a word "random word", but you can use something like this:

```
[A-Z\d]*\d[A-Z\d]*[A-Z][A-Z\d]*
```

This is a word that contains at least a digit and at least a non-digit character. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKY9jp/1).

Or maybe you can use:

```
\b\d[A-Z\d]*[A-Z][A-Z\d]*
```

dor a word that starts with a digit and contains at least a non-digit character. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKY9jp/2).

Or if you want to combine exactly those regex, use.

```
\b\d[A-Z]\d(X\d|\d{2}[A-Z]?)?\b
```

See the final [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKY9jp/3).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find "words" where there are both digits and letters mixed, the easiest is to use the word-boundary operator, `\b`; but notice that you need to use `r''` strings / escape the `\` in the code (which you would need to do for the `\d` anyway in future Python versions). To match any sequence of alphanumeric characters separated by word boundary, you could use

```
r'\b[0-9A-Z]+\b'
```

However, this wouldn't yet guarantee that there is at least one number and at least one letter. For that we will use positive zero-width lookahead assertion `(?= )` which means that the whole regex matches only if the contained pattern matches at that point. We need 2 of them: one ensures that there is at least one digit and one that there is at least one letter:

```
>>> p = r'\b(?=[0-9A-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9A-Z]*[A-Z])[0-9A-Z]+\b'
>>> re.findall(p, '1A A1 32 AA 1A123B')
['1A', 'A1', '1A123B']
```

This will now match everything including `33333A` or `AAAAAAAAAA3A` for as long as there is at least one digit and one letter. However if the pattern will always start with a digit and always contain a letter, it becomes slightly easier, for example:

```
>>> p = r'\b\d+[A-Z][0-9A-Z]*\b'
>>> re.findall(p, '1A A1 32 AA 1A123B')
['1A', '1A123B']
```

i.e. A1 didn't match because it doesn't start with a digit.